# Transfer money between Wells Fargo and BofA accounts for free

Tags: united-states, transfer, bank-of-america, free

Is there a free way to transfer money from a Wells Fargo account to a Bank of America account?

I looked into wire transfers, and it turns out that they have a fee associated with them. The only other method I came up with (aside from manually withdrawing/depositing cash from ATMs) was to create a second [Venmo](http://www.venmo.com) account and transfer money to myself that way, though that seems a bit hacky.

Comment: Wells Fargo's FAQ [here](https://www.wellsfargo.com/help/faqs/transfers/) says "there may be fees for transfers to your bank accounts at other Financial Institutions [...] please refer to your Fee and Account Information Schedule".  I think it will depend on the type of account you have.  You are best off contacting the two banks directly to see what options you have for your accounts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest method is just to write a check from one account and deposit it in the other.  If you are the owner of both accounts, you should be able to electronically deposit the check using their phone apps.  Depending on the amount you are transfering, it may take a few days for the check to clear.

Answer (score 14):

Wells Fargo and Bank of America both belong to the clearXchange bank network (https://www.clearxchange.com/about).  You can send money to anyone for free with just their email address or phone number if you both use one of these banks:

- **Bank of America** ("Send Money To Someone")
- **Capital One** ("P2P Payments")
- **Chase** ("QuickPay℠")
- **FirstBank** ("Person to Person Transfers")
- **U.S. Bank** ("Send Money")
- **Wells Fargo** ("SurePay℠")

(Check the list on the clearXchange website, as the above list may change.)

That means you can easily transfer money from a Wells Fargo account to a Bank of America account using Wells Fargo's "SurePay".  To go the other direction, on the Bank of America website click on the "Transfers" tab, then go to Send Money To Someone -> "Using their email address or mobile number".

Comment: @Ryan - Please consider changing the accepted answer to the above. I have done banking with cheques, and it is still a highly manual process (mobile app included... Scan both sides, enter in amount on cheque, etc, etc, etc). You can literally login to your bank, navigate to the correct part of the UI and enter in receiving account and amount, click send and done. In addition, this answer provides exactly the named part of the UI to go to.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ideas:

- In Bank of America's online banking, you can go to Transfers -> between my accounts -> at other banks. I believe that inbound transfers (from another bank to Bank of America, which is the direction you want) are free. (For the other direction, Wells Fargo similarly has an online transfer service between your accounts where inbound (from another bank to Wells Fargo) is free.)
- Use Wells Fargo SurePay to pay yourself. It's meant for paying other people, but I don't see why it can't be used to pay yourself.